# move int through activitys without changing the activity

Tags: android, android-intent

So I'm trying to get an integer from from 2 different activitys to 1 activity. right now i use intent and my code takes me to activity of the intent instead of only sending the integer and staying on the activity any help on how I do it? If I remove `startActivity` then activity c just crashes when trying to open it... been trying for hours now.

example. page 1 have "int a = 1;" page 2 have "int b=2;" both of these are needed on the last page

```
//First Activity
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("MY_KEY", 15);
startActivity(i);

//Second Activity
int number = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("MY_KEY");
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. You speak of 3 activities: A, B and C, but you provide code from 2 activities. It also isn't clear what you mean "without changing the activity". Please edit your question and explain your problem better.

Comment: tried editting but real hard to explain

Comment: Do you ever open the `FirstActivity` & `SecondActivity`?

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand your problem. Post more code or a screen shot or something.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Page 1
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("MY_KEY", 15);
startActivity(i);

//Page 2
int number = getIntent().getIntExtra("MY_KEY");
Intent i2 = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
i2.putExtra("MY_KEY", number);
i2.putExtra("MY_KEY_TWO", 20);
// Or i2.putExtra("MY_KEY", new int[]{number,20});
startActivity(i2);

//Page 3
Intent in = getIntent();
int number = in.getIntExtra("MY_KEY");
int number2  = in.getIntExtra("MY_KEY_TWO");
// Or int numbers[]=in.getIntArrayExtra("MY_KEY");
```

Comment: thankyou this is how it need to be done just wish there was a smarter way

Comment: You can create a separate class to hold your keys and declare those variables as static. Then assign values in your pages or activities and get values by calling Holder.key1 and Holder.key2